# BDD Test Angular App with TestCafe - page reload

Tags: angular, testing, bdd, gherkin, testcafe

I'm trying to use TestCafe running BDD test against the Angular app.

And we got an account page like:

http://localhost:8080/main#/account

In the testing steps, we have

- When User go to the account page
- Then User waited for 20 seconds in the page
- Then User go to the account page

in the 1st and 3rd step, we implemented using TestCafe

```
await t.navigateTo(http://localhost:8080/main#/account);
```

As the hashtag is not triggering a page reload, so no server call/api call would happen, as I'm testing session related feature, expecting some reload/hard refresh happening here.

Anyone come across similar requirements?

Comment: location.reload(true) to make the hard refresh.

Comment: Tried with await t.eval(() => location.reload(true)), but it just hanging on that step

Comment: Found this sample: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56157048/testcafe-how-to-reload-actual-page, question here is do I have to use fixture to make it work?

Comment: The `await t.eval(() => location.reload(true))`  command should not hang test execution. Could you please provide an example with which it's possible to reproduce the problem?

Comment: we are using 
"cucumber": "^5.1.0",
"gherkin-testcafe": "^2.4.0",
"testcafe": "^1.3.3"

so in the steps I got
`When('User go to account page', async (t) => {

  await t.eval(() => location.reload(true));
//await t.navigateTo(http://localhost:8080/main#/account);
});`

Comment: This description is not sufficient to reproduce the problem. Please create a sample project that will demonstrate the issue on our machines. Use the following template to create the issue: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md
Besides I want to mention that the `gherkin-testcafe` is not supported by TestCafe team, so probably it's better to ask them for help in the `gherkin-testcafe` github repository.

Comment: I raised a ticket in "gherkin-testcafe", but they mentioned it could be some issue in TestCafe. But I fixed the issue by increase timeout after the client function e.g. t.wait(10000); 

It would be really good if TestCafe can have a proper support or api for page reload.

Comment: We are considering this functionality as a potential enhancement for future TestCafe updates. You can subscribe to [this issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/4049) to be informed of our progress.